# How to close Access Connection using accessdb API?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the  [accessdb.sourceforge.net](http://accessdb.sourceforge.net/)  documentation but could not find how to close a connection.

Here is how to open connection :

`myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\dbfile.mdb", {showErrors:true});`

I tried closing it

```
myDB = null;
```

This works sometimes . Is there any method to close a connection with this API ?

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect, try using `kill()` method on the `ACCESSdb` object:

```
var myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\dbfile.mdb", {showErrors:true});
myDB.kill();
```

**Reason**:

You can find in the `accessdb.js`, the definition of the `kill()` method like following:

```
  this.kill = function() {
     this.conn.close();
     delete this;
  };
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: I tried `kill()`. It says this m=property is not defined

Comment: It also says : `cannot delete this`

Comment: @Alex: Have you ever tried executing some simple accessdb example? Did it work?

Comment: @Alex: ACCESSdb is using ActiveXObject. ActiveX is an IE-specific technology, meaning that if you try using ActiveX in browsers except IE, it won't work, it'll give you the "...is not defined" error. As you see in my answer, kill method starts by closing the property conn. This property conn is an ActiveXObject.

Comment: Of course I am using IE . And yes I am aware of the ActiveX , and no other browser supports that natively. It does not work . The first thing I tried was reading the library

Answer (score 0):

I found out the correct way for anybody who will encounter this problem.  `delete`  is not recognized. So, the correct way to close the connection is as following

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="system/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="system/accessdb.js"></script> 
<script>
myDB = new ACCESSdb("C\\test.mdb", {showErrors:true}); 
alert("connection successful"); 
myDB.conn.close();  // use .conn.close() DO NOT use "delete"  
} 
catch (err) {
alert(err);      // no error thrown here   
}
alert("connection closed");
</script>
</html>
```